# Attask Adding New Project Using Template

Tags: attask, workfront-api

How can i add new project using our template created ? is there any one knows?
lack of API Documentation with no examples of adding templates and no examples of Adding New Project Using Template. Please Help...!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a [mcve] detailing the code you have tried thus far. Explain why it does not work and what the expected results are.

Answer (score 2):

You should create project as usual just defining `templateID` field in addition.

```
POST /attask/api/v5.0/project HTTP/1.1
Host: <yourdomain>.attask-ondemand.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

name=your project name&templateID=55f7...5ed2&sessionID=f9de...12c5
```

Comment: Thanks i got it by myself i and see your answer today :) But really appreciate your help. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For those that would like to see the c# code.  Here is how I got this to work.

```
  [HttpGet]
    public void CreateProject()
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dictionary.Add("name", "my test project 1");
        dictionary.Add("templateID", "1234567890"); //pre-existing template id
        dictionary.Add("sessionID", _sessionID);
        try
        {
            var postResponse = Post_HttpResponseMessage("project", dictionary);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }


private HttpResponseMessage Post_HttpResponseMessage(string taskToPerform, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> postData)
{
    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage;

    using (var apiManagementSystem = new HttpClient())
    {
        apiManagementSystem.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://mycompany.preview.workfront.com/attask/api/");
        apiManagementSystem.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

        var jsonMediaType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
        apiManagementSystem.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(jsonMediaType);
        apiManagementSystem.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SessionID", _sessionID);

        HttpContent httpContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

        responseMessage = apiManagementSystem.PostAsync(taskToPerform, httpContent).Result;
    }
    return responseMessage;
}
```